# Firebase Password reset using custom domain not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I've configure custom domain using Firebase hosting and connected it for password reset purpose. My relevant deployed code as follows.

```
function handleResetPasswordSection(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {

  var accountEmail;

  auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
    var accountEmail = email;
    actionCode = actionCode;

    var newPassword = document.getElementById("newPasswordInput").value;

    auth.confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
      var messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");
      var successDiv = document.getElementById("success");

      messageDiv.style.display = "none";
      successDiv.style.display = "block";
      // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.


    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      var messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");

      messageDiv.style.display = "none";

      var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
      errorDiv.style.display = "block";
      $("#error > p").text(error.message);

    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");

    messageDiv.style.display = "none";

    var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
    errorDiv.style.display = "block";
    $("#error > p").text(error.message);

  });
}

function handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {
  auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {

  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");

    messageDiv.style.display = "none";

    var errorDiv = document.getElementById("error");
    errorDiv.style.display = "block";
    $("#error > p").text(error.message);

  });  
}
```

Recover email successfully sent and after click on that link it shows to enter new password and suddenly displays the error `The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.`. Why this happens?

Comment: Check the network tab in the browser console for more details on the error. This will provide more actionable information on what is going on.